Xorg, Wayland and share screen in Ubuntu 22.04 vs Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04
I have some problems with screen sharing (impossible in viber, discord, skype etc and I need those apps) in Ubuntu 22.04 (using wayland) and I would like to find a solution. I searched around the internet and found some posts in different forums.
Here and here are some. I have Nvidia graphics card and since I changed from 18.04 to 22.04 I noticed some lagging, but that wasn't the case with 18.04.
I was thinking about changing to ubuntu cinnamon because I read that it uses xorg as default (hoping that it will resolve my problem) and because it is more ``lightweight'' for my computer.
The question is: should I be aware of something before the change? For example, I read that xorg isn't that safe. Maybe something I don't know about ubuntu cinnamon that would keep me from installing them?
Edit: If Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04 makes the post off-topic for this site I must say I have no problem installing 23.10 or 24.04 version but I have no idea whether they use wayland or xorg.

Ubuntu Cinnamon isn't a flavor but a respin before Ubuntu 23.04; thus Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04 LTS is not on-topic on this site. Ubuntu Cinnamon has releases for 23.10 & 24.04 LTS that are official flavors & thus on-topic here.   Refer https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2023-March/005585.html and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Xorg used to be X11; with version X.ver11 dating back to 1987.. where network security was somewhat less of a concern than today. X11 may have changed name, but Xorg didn't improve that security model any, and Wayland helps address security issues; alas security can get in the way of desktop sharing!  If you use 22.04 with Ubuntu Cinnamon, don't forget it's off-topic here, but deciding how much security matters to you is for you to decide; using Xorg will reduce security over Wayland (one of the reasons for Wayland is the higher security model), and security can cost cycles (tad slower)

I feel trapped. Maybe I should search for another solution.

Just a comment for anyone that will have the same dilemma and wants to learn pros and cons. Cinammon uses x11 still in 24.04. Although the problems with screen sharing disappered, screen is shaking every now and then. It doesn't lag, but for some reason battery is consumed a lot faster than before.
